# How do I create a time boxed lookup of events in Python 3?

Tags: python, arrays, list, caching, dictionary

I am dealing with event data (in this case USGS earthquakes). USGS give you e.g. the last hour or last day of all earthquakes and updates that list every few minutes. 
I need to poll that list every minute and act on new events in that list but ignore those I have acted on.

I can easily create a list that I add new quake events to it:

```
events = list()
for f in features:

    event = [{
        'name': 'usgs.earthquake.feature', # Time Series Name
        'columns': ['id', 'long', 'lat', 'depth', 'mag', 'type'\
                    'magtype', 'tz', 'felt', 'place', 'status'\
                    'gap', 'dmin', 'rms', 'ids', 'title', 'types'\
                    'cdi', 'net', 'nst', 'sources', 'alert', 'time'\
                    'tsunami', 'code', 'sig'
                    ], # Keys
        'points': [[ f['id'],\
                     f['geometry']['coordinates'][0],\
                     f['geometry']['coordinates'][1],\
                     f['geometry']['coordinates'][2],\
                     f['properties']['mag'],\
                     f['properties']['type'],\
                     f['properties']['magType'],\
                     f['properties']['tz'],\
                     ...
                     f['properties']['time'],\
                     f['properties']['tsunami'],\
                     f['properties']['code'],\
                     f['properties']['sig']
                      ]] # Data points
    }]

    if event in events:
        log.debug('Surpressing duplicate event id: %s', event[0]['points'][0][0])
    else:
        log.debug('Event data: %s', event)

        events.insert(0, event)

        handler.postEvent(event)

    log.debug('Event Cache Count: %s', len(events))
```

Is that a smart way - building a lookup via a list like that?
How do I best maintain the past 2h or 36h in the list while dropping off older entires?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got an `id` field, I suggest you can work with a dict instead of a list. (but the `id` has to unique, I don't know if this is the case)

```
events = {
    'eventid': Event()
}
```

This way your query, if the event is already saved, works a expected.

```
if event in events:
    [..ignore..]
```

and if not already there: add it to the dict:

```
events[eventid] = Event(..data..)
```

If you also save the event timestamp or datetime in the meta Event object, then you can easily loop trough the events dict and remove events older than a certain time with the "`del`" statement. Lets say your datetime field ist named `dt`. Then you can do something like this:

```
for eventid, event_data in d.items():
    if datetime.utcnow() - event_data['dt'] > timedelta(minutes=20):
        del events[eventid]
```

this will expire events older than 20 min.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While the id is unique to the event, events can get updated with newer more accurate information, in which case I need to reprocess the event. That's why I initially went with the list instead of an id based dict, so I can identify if any part of the vent I just received is different from existing ones in the cache. That however means I cannot attached a timestamp to the incoming event for when it arrived on my end or I would not be able to compare the full event any more.

Comment: I would still recommend to go with the dict. If you have the id, you can simply remove the event from the dict, in case you receive an updated one. Comparing a hole lot of arguments and data is more expensive (cpu, memory) and therefore slower. Except you want to track the changes, but then you need some better logic anyway.